# Place rectangles minimizing unused space

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing-problem

Given a set of rectangles $S := \{R_1, R_2, ..., R_n\}$, I want to place them on a canvas such that the bounding box contains as little unused space as possible. Rectangles must not overlap. Rotation is not allowed.

The canvas can be thought of as infinite in $x$ and $y$.

A rectangle $R_i$ is given by the coordinates of its left, top, right and bottom edges, $(l_i, t_i, r_i, b_i)$. The area a rectangle occupies is defined by all $(x, y)$ where $x >= l_i$ and $x < r_i$ and $y >= t_i$ and $y < b_i$.

To place rectangle $R_i$ on the canvas, choose a position $(x, y)$ and use this for the rectangle's top-left corner. That is, remove $R_i$ from the set, and add a new $R_i' := (x, y, x + (r_i - l_i), y + (b_i - t_i))$ to the set. The new rectangle $R_i'$ has the same width and height as the original $R_i$.

The bounding box is defined as a rectangle $B(S):=(l_{bb}, t_{bb}, r_{bb}, b_{bb})$ where $l_{bb}$ is the minimum of $l_i$ in all rectangles $R_i$ in $S$; $r_{bb}$ is the maximum of all $r_i$; $t_{bb}$ is the minimum of all $t_i$; and $b_{bb}$ is the maximum of all $b_i$. Thus, it depends on the positioning and size of each rectangle.

The unused space is the area of all $(x, y)$ inside $B$ for which there is no $R_i$ that overlaps that area. I want to miminise the unused space. Since the sizes of $R_i$ is fixed, minimising the unused space is the same as minimising the area of the bounding box $A(S) := (r_{bb} - l_{bb}) * (b_{bb} - t_{bb})$.

The algorithm should also prefer solutions whose bounding box resembles more a square than a rectangle. Thus, I want to minimise the score $Z(S) := k*A(S) + |(r_{bb} - l_{bb}) - (b_{bb} - t_{bb})|$. The score increases with the area of $B$ as well as with non-squareness of $B$ given by the difference of B's width and height. The factor $k$ is a constant that is large enough to make minimising the area much more important than the solution's squareness.

Although I'm interested in finding the optimal solution, this is not a requirement. I'm happy with an approximation, especially if it's simple.

(Application: I have a number of small texture images and I want to combine them to one large image that contains all of the given images, but does not use a lot more memory because of unused areas.)

Comment: As I understand it, the dimensions of the bounding rectangle aren't known beforehand ? Is it right ? If, otherwise, these dimensions are known right at the beginning, the problem is completely different : if such is the case, the problem is "find if it is possible to cover the rectangle with the given rectangles, and in which way".

Comment: Yes, the dimension of the bounding box is defined as written in the question, and thus is a result from the positions. The width and height of each rectangle $R_i$ is known, of course.

Comment: It sounds like all your rectangles are meant to be aligned with the coordinate axes, although this is not stated in the question. It should be. If you are familiar with the bin-packing problem, a much simpler problem for which no one knows a good algorithm, then you might suspect that there is no good algorithm for your problem, either.

Comment: How big is $n$?

Comment: "aligned with the coordinate axes" means the sides are vertical and horizontal.

Comment: $n$ will usually be between 100 and 1000.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use mixed integer linear programming.

Your proposed objective function is nonlinear, but to get a linear objective function you could instead minimize the sum of width and height, with bounds on their difference to force the bounding box to be squarish.

See https://yetanothermathprogrammingconsultant.blogspot.com/2017/07/rectangles-no-overlap-constraints.html for details about how to impose constraints that prevent overlapping rectangles.